# What approximate amount of semistructured data is enough for setting up Hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I know, Hadoop is not only alternative for semistructured data processing in general — I can do many things with plain tab-separated data and a bunch of unix tools (cut, grep, sed, ...) and hand-written python scripts. But sometimes I get really big amounts of data and processing time goes up to 20-30 minutes. It's unacceptable to me, because I want experiment with dataset dynamically, running some semi-ad-hoc queries and etc.

So, what amount of data do you consider enough to setting Hadoop cluster in terms of cost-results of this approach?

Answer (score 2):

Without know exactly what you're doing, here are my suggestions:

- If you want to run ad-hoc queries on the data, Hadoop is not the best way to go.  Have you tried loading your data into a database and running queries on that?
- If you want to experiment with using Hadoop without the cost of setting up a cluster, try using Amazon's Elastic MapReduce offering http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/
- I've personally seen people get pretty far using shell scripting for these kinds of tasks.  Have you tried distributing your work over machines using SSH?  GNU Parallel makes this pretty easy: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue has several aspects. The first one - what you can achieve with usual SQL technologies like MySQL/Oracle etc. If you can get solution with them - I think it will be better solution.

Should be also pointed out that hadoop processing of tabular data will be much slower then conventional DBMS. So I am getting to the second aspect - are you ready to build hadoop cluster with more then 4 machines? I think 4-6 machines is a bare minimum to feel some gains.

Third aspect is - are your ready to wait for data loading to the database - it can take time, but then queries will be fast. So if you makes a few queries for each dataset - it is in hadoop advantage.

Returning to the original question - I think that you need at least 100-200 GB of data so Hadoop processing will have some sense. 2 TB I think is a clear indication that hadoop might be a good choice.